# Single Input Form - Save button below or to side?

Tags: forms, buttons, layout, input-fields, bootstrap

I'm playing around with Bootstrap's Input Group Addons and I'm struggling to decide which is better from a UX perspective.

[image]

versus:

[image]

This is a single input form to add priorities to a list (for example: High, Medium, Low priorities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, since there's only one input at a time, I would place it **next to the input.** The user will already be reading from left to right and will end up at the button, one direction.

If it would be an entire form the user would also read from top to bottom (in Z-shapes) and it would make more sense to place the button at the bottom of the form.

Answer (score 2):

**None of them.**

If you're adding priorities, you should use a `select` or `radio buttons`, not a text input.

Now, if the options are only those 3, then `radio buttons` is the answer. Otherwise, if you have more than 5 options, you should use the `select` element. ([here's the reasoning](http://uxmovement.com/forms/stop-misusing-select-menus/))

After that, the placement of buttons will depend on whether you have more fields or not. If this is just a single field, then you can inline both, otherwise, you'll obviously need to place the button at the bottom (duh!). UI considerations may apply as well (design, spacing, layout, etc)

Anyways, in general, specially with Bootstrap, try to use buttons BELOW each field, or you'll end with a field on the left, then the button for that field may be located like 1000px to the right!

Comment: the 3 priorities are just examples, the user may enter 'extra high', 'sorta high'. This form allows the user to add any number of priorities. (this is a management form) This data essentially becomes the options of a dropdown used elsewhere in the application.

Comment: in terms of UX, you need to define those options. You can even create them dynamically if needed, but randomness is not recommended in UX. If you need to add 10 priorities, then so be it, and use a *select* element as mentioned in the answer

Comment: @Devin I think AzNjoE wants to give the users the freedom to use their own prioritizing-system. Although I agree that maybe the user should have the option to pre-define its own system of priorities and then still will have the radio buttons, based on his own defined priorities.

Comment: @Luchadora, I get that, but he also says *"which is better from a UX perspective"*. From an UX perspective, the answer is **none of them**, this is what is known as an anti-pattern. There are many reasons why he  shouldn't do this, both *back end* and *front end* ones. Just to mention a few: **inconsistency, randomness, DB issues, lack of control, unexpected affordances**.